# Identify this chip is on a Dell OptiPlex 745 motherboard

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, identification, motherboard

I have a Dell OptiPlex 745 motherboard. I am unable to identify the below chip.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Probably this guy’s bigger brother, or that first 8 is actually a 6. Can you take a photo from a different angle and zoom out a bit?

[image]

[Datasheet](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=312082&part-number=FAN5068MP)

FAN5068 is a voltage regulator for DDR memory.

FAN5088 may be a customized product for Dell and not sold elsewhere with no datasheet available.

Comment: It's an 8 so it's a fan5088

Comment: @VoltageSpike No results on FAN5088. If OP responds with a zoomed out image and it’s close to the RAM, I would assume it’s a brother of FAN5068.